# Using GenServer in channel. How to persist pid?

Tags: phoenix-framework

I am calling a GenServer in my channel class. The GenServer needs a pid. How can I persist that pid so that every time when the join method in the GenServer is called, I can invoke GenServer with that same pid? Should I save it in socket params or should I pass it back and forth between the channel and the front end javascript?

Answer (score 3):

I was struggling with similar problem myself lately I choose to use names instead of pids when dealing with GenServers. You can pass `name` parameter to `GenServer.start_link/3` and then use it in other calls (e.g. `GenServer.cast/2`. In my case I'm using unique ids sent to channel to generate names for the server (for example: `:"document-1"`).

The biggest drawback of this approach is that BEAM has a limit on number of atoms, so it can crash if the number of generated names is too big, so you have to think about it when implementing this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The way I've gotten around this is passing `socket.topic` to a GenServer process since a socket's pid can change if a client refreshes their browser.

From the GenServer, you can broadcast back to the topic with `MyApp.Endpoint.broadcast! socket_topic, "some_notification", message`.
You can intercept the message within your channel and handle it if you choose or push it straight to the client.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly the genserver process created inside a phoenix channel is linked to the channel process. So you might want to unlink the genserver process from the channel. And then do name registration for your process so that the same pid would persist.